# Is it possible for a modem to connect to an APN using GSM only, not GPRS?

Tags: gsm, gprs, apn

Using a 2g/gprs modem (BGS2T), it seems like we are able to connect to an APN and communicate data though it with only a GSM connection. Is it possible we are doing this without a pdp context being active between the the modem (mobile station) and the SGSN (Serving gprs support node)/ actually using GPRS?

Comment: I think this question would be better adressed in the more specific QA site Telecommunications proposed here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/104688/telecommunications
If you like the proposal, ask your question there and follow the proposal as well

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a TCP/IP connection over the circuit switched GSM voice network then the only way you can do normally is by using a data modem over the speech path.

It is possible to do that but it would be an unusual way to do data, especially with the different network options available today.

The modem you mention is a GPRS modem however, so it is much more likely you are actually using a GPRS connection.